# Can a table be declared as an object in T-SQL like it can in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, t-sql

I have code similar to the following in Entity Framework

```
COMPANY defaultCompany = (from T in db.COMPANY where T.id = 2).FirstOrDefault();

COMPANYAUDIT ca = new COMPANYAUDIT();
ca.companyID = defaultCompany.id;
ca.companyName = defaultCompany.companyName;
ca.volumeID = defaultCompany.volumeID;

db.COMPANYAUDIT.Add(ca);
db.SaveChanges();
```

I want to be able to do the same thing in a stored procedure using T-SQL.  Is there a way to declare a table object or variable so I can access the various columns in the table to be used to insert data into another table?  Basically I need to take data from one table and use that to insert a new record into another table. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use insert from select
see: [sql_insert_into_select](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert_into_select.asp)

somthing like this

```
insert into COMPANYAUDIT(companyID, companyName, volumeID)
select id, companyName, volumeID
from COMPANY
where id = 2
```